# i got error message locating in a line, but i cannot figure it out why it is wrong

Tags: java

i got error message locating in this line "radiusToSelect[p*(p-1)/2+q]=distanceBetweenParticles[p][q];", but i cannot figure it out why it is wrong.

java code is following, really appreciation for your help.

this is the error message "2.04.02.06.04.02.08.0Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at javaAndR.soswarm.main(soswarm.java:59)"

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        double [][] score=new double [40][4];
        double [][] id=new double [1000][4];
        int row, column;
        int [][] bmu=new int[id.length][1];
        double [][] shortestdistance=new double [id.length][1];
        double [][] distance=new double[id.length][score.length];
        double [][] distanceBetweenParticles= new double[score.length][score.length];

        double[] radiusToSelect=new double [(score[1].length-1)*(score[1].length)/2];



        for(row=0;row<score.length;row++)
        {
            for(column=0;column<score[row].length;column++)
            {
                score[row][column]=row+column;

            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        for (int i =0;i<id.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<id[row].length;j++)
            {
                id[i][j]=i*j;
                //System.out.print(id[i][j]+" ");               
            }
            //System.out.print("\n");

        }

        for (int p=1;p<score.length;p++)
        {
            for(int q=0;q<p;q++)
            {
                distanceBetweenParticles[p][q]=distance(score[p][0],score[p][1],score[p][2],score[p][3],score[q][0],score[q][1],score[q][2],score[q][3]);
                System.out.print(distanceBetweenParticles[p][q]);
                radiusToSelect[p*(p-1)/2+q]=distanceBetweenParticles[p][q];
            }
        }

         int first; double temp;  
         for (int a = radiusToSelect.length - 1; a > 0; a--)  
         {
              first = 0;   //initialize to subscript of first element
              for(int b = 1; b <= a; b ++)   //locate smallest element between positions 1 and i.
              {
                   if( radiusToSelect[ b ] < radiusToSelect[ first ] )         
                     first = b;
              }
              temp = radiusToSelect[first];   //swap smallest found with element in position i.
              radiusToSelect[ first ] = radiusToSelect[ a ];
              radiusToSelect[ a ] = temp; 
          }  
         double radius=radiusToSelect[((int) radiusToSelect.length*2/3)];
         System.out.println(radius+" "+"\n");


        for(int ite=0;ite<10;ite++)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<score.length;j++)
            {

                distance[i][j]=distance(score[j][0],score[j][1],score[j][2],score[j][3],id[i][0],id[i][1],id[i][2],id[i][3]);
            }



            for(int u=0;u<distance[i].length-1;u++) 
            {
                if(distance[i][u]>distance[i][u+1])
                {

                shortestdistance[i][0]=distance[i][u+1];
                bmu[i][0]=u+1;

                }
                else
                {
                shortestdistance[i][0]=distance[i][u];
                bmu[i][0]=u;
                }

            }

        for(int s=0;s<score[1].length;s++)
        {
            for(int t=0;t<score[1].length;t++)
        {

            score[s][t]=score[s][t]*gaussian(score[t][0],score[t][1],score[t][2],score[t][3],score[bmu[i][0]][0],score[bmu[i][0]][1],score[bmu[i][0]][2],score[bmu[i][0]][3],radius);
            System.out.print("id "+score[bmu[i][0]][t]+" ");
        }

        //System.out.print("\n");


        }}


                /*System.out.println(score[row][0]);*/


            /*System.out.println(score[row][0]);*/
    }
    }

    public static double distance (double x1,double x2,double x3,double x4,double y1,double y2,double y3,double y4)
    {
        return Math.sqrt((y1 - x1) * (y1 - x1) + (y2 - x2) * (y2 - x2) + (y3 - x3) * (y3 - x3) + (y4 - x4) * (y4 - x4));
    }
    public static double gaussian (double x1,double x2,double x3,double x4,double y1,double y2,double y3,double y4,double r)
    {
        return Math.exp(-(distance (x1,x2,x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4))/2/r/r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why post all the other lines? Why not post the error message?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Error looks like it's in this line:

```
radiusToSelect[p*(p-1)/2+q]=distanceBetweenParticles[p][q];
```

`radiusToSelect` has a length of `(score[1].length-1)*(score[1].length)/2` which is 6 (3*4/2). `p` can be as large as 39, and q as large as 38, so it will easily exceed the size of the array.